# I am not able to create customised columns when using grid template areas

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to customise my header's columns to be 24vw 24vw 4vw 24vw 24vw. However, the browser is rendering all columns to be of equal width. I am not able to change the width of the centered div for some reason. When I don't use grid template area, I have no problems. But when I am using it, I can't seem to solve it. Why is it happening? Any help?

```
    HTML code:
   

     <div class="head-grid-container">
                <!-- This will be my white banner area. Logos and place name will go here. -->
                <div class="logo-section"> 
                    <div class="logo"><img src="government-logo.png" /></div>
                    <div class="name"><h2 style="font-family: 'Kalam', cursive;">Durbar</h2></div>
                    <div class="logo"><img src="../Visual/logo.png" /></div>
                    <div class="name"><h2 style="font-family: 'La Belle Aurore', cursive;">Durbar</h2></div>
                    <div class="logo"><img src="world-heritage-site-logo.png" /></div>
                </div>
                 <!-- This will be my red banner area. Navigation links will go here. -->
                <div class="links-section">
                    <div class="links-left"><h2 class="left">Palace</h2></div>
                    <div class="links-left"><h2 class="left">Museum</h2></div>
                    <div class="center-logo"><img src="../Visual/home.svg" /></div>
                    <div class="links-right"><h2 class="right">Supervision Office</h2></div>
                    <div class="links-right"><h2 class="right">Development Committee</h2></div>
                </div>
                <!-- This will be my yellow section -->
                <div class="showcase-section">
                    <div class="links-left"></div>
                    <div class="links-left"></div>
                    <div class="center-logo"></div>
                    <div class="links-right"></div>
                    <div class="links-right"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
    CSS code:
/* heading grid container customisation */
.head-grid-container{
    display: grid;
    height: 20vh;
    width: 100vw;
    grid-template-columns: 24vw 24vw 4vw 24vw 24vw;
    grid-template-rows: 13vh 6vh 1vh;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "white white white white white"
    "red red red red red"
    "yellow yellow yellow yellow yellow";
}
/* make all the boxes inside the grid table float next to each other using display as flex */
.logo-section{
    grid-area: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    box-shadow: 2px 8px 8px -6px #141414;
    z-index: 5;
}
.links-section{
    grid-area: red;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: #d30d0d;
    z-index: 4;
    color:#f5f5f5;
    font-family: 'Bebas Neue', cursive;
    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 4px -6px #141414;
}
.showcase-section{
    grid-area: yellow;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: #fec52a;
    z-index: 3;
}
/* make the contents inside grid present at the center of the table */
.logo-section>div, .links-section>div{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
}
/* image width modification */
.logo>img{
    height: 80px;
}
.center-logo>img{
    height: 30px;
}
/*apply shadows to borders*/
.links-left{
    box-shadow: -5px 0px 20px -3px #141414;
}
.links-right{
    box-shadow: 5px 0px 20px -3px #141414;
}
.center-logo{
    box-shadow: 5px 0px 20px -3px #141414, -5px 0px 20px -3px #141414;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.head-grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 24vw 24vw 4vw 24vw 24vw !important;
    grid-gap: 1px;
    background-color: #2196F3;
   width:100vw !important;
  }
  
  .head-grid-container > div {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
.logo>img{
    height: 80px;
}
.center-logo>img{
    height: 30px;
   
}
/*apply shadows to borders*/
.links-left{
    box-shadow: -5px 0px 20px -3px #141414;
}
.links-right{
    box-shadow: 5px 0px 20px -3px #141414;
}
.center-logo{
    box-shadow: 5px 0px 20px -3px #141414, -5px 0px 20px -3px #141414;
}
```

```html
<div class="head-grid-container">
  <!-- This will be my white banner area. Logos and place name will go here. -->

      <div class="first logo"><img src="government-logo.png" /></div>
      <div class="first name"><h2 style="font-family: 'Kalam', cursive;">Durbar</h2></div>
      <div class="first logo"><img src="../Visual/logo.png" /></div>
      <div class="first name"><h2 style="font-family: 'La Belle Aurore', cursive;">Durbar</h2></div>
      <div class="first logo"><img src="world-heritage-site-logo.png" /></div>
 
   <!-- This will be my red banner area. Navigation links will go here. -->
 
      <div class="second links-left"><h2 class="left">Palace</h2></div>
      <div class="second links-left"><h2 class="left">Museum</h2></div>
      <div class="second center-logo"><img src="../Visual/home.svg" /></div>
      <div class="second links-right"><h2 class="right">Supervision Office</h2></div>
      <div class="second links-right"><h2 class="right">Development Committee</h2></div>

  <!-- This will be my yellow section -->

      <div class="third links-left"></div>
      <div class="third links-left"></div>
      <div class="third center-logo"></div>
      <div class="third links-right"></div>
      <div class="third links-right"></div>

</div>
```

Actually you are expecting it to be a 3rows X 5columns grid but actually there are 3 nested div which is making it to be a grid of 1row X 3columns.
I applied some basic css and removed the nested divs.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. That does make sense. However, I tried your code and realized that if I do so, I won't have a grid-area at all. How can I have the grid area as you posed it: 3rows x 5 columns. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I snippet I actually mentioned is a grid of 3rows X 5 colums as specified by  
`grid-template-columns:24vw 24vw 4vw 24vw 24vw; //5 values for 5 columns
grid-template-rows:16vw 10vw 6vw;//3 values for 3 rows`  You can give in `grid-template-columns:100vw` in your question code and it will work 3rows X 1Column with the nested divs

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped